# What is a clean approach in Xcode 12.2 to add a Core Data file to an older Xcode project?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

> **Update: I fixed this by adding title and date attributes to the Data Model, and also a timestamp attribute required by the persistence class. Compiling I found other errors, that I am currently fixing. Xcode 12 introduces a different structure of the PersistenceController, that I think that simplifies the use, but older code needs a bit of refactoring. I am leaving the post here if it can be of any help.**

I am using the most recent Xcode on Big Sur to add CoreData to extend a project that didn't have it, and I am getting this error:

```
/Users/myroot/Desktop/Development/myapp/app/AppDelegate.swift:61:45: Argument passed to call that takes no arguments
```

When I try to copy the content of an Xcode 12.2 Persistence.swift example project in my old application project AppDelegate.swift, I get the error in the PersistenceController, in this block of code that includes:

```
let newItem = Item(context: viewContext)
```

Has anyone solved how to update a project using AppDelegate.swift with an Xcode 12.2 Core Data code that didn't use it?

Thanks.

Comment: Did you at least `import CoreData`?

Comment: I did, but I didn't add the attributes to the Data Model file. I am going to update the post above.